# How to test rails application with mongodb(mongoid) backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoid

The simple controller testing code works in a SQL backend rails application, but not in the mongodb backend rails application.

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsController < ActiveController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

While running `rake --verbose test`, no normal successful output and it exits & prints nothing.

Any clue what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the root cause of the problem. When `require "rails/test_unit/railtie"` is added to config/application.rb, the test can be run without problem.